# Laravel - How to only enable Add Button based on condition

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel-8 project with this model:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_id',
              'leave_status',
              'commencement_date',
              'resumption_date',
              'created_at'
          ];

protected $dates = [
    'commencement_date',
    'resumption_date',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
];
```

View:

```html
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    @if ($currentstatus)

    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route(" service.leave_requests.create ") }}">
                        Add
                    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endif

  </div>
</div>
```

I want the Add button to only be visible when:

1. leave_status is 0 for the last record (order by created_at)

or

2. leave_status is 4 and resumption_date is greater than or equal to today's date (order by created_at) for the last record.

or

3. leave_status is 3 (order by created_at) for the last record.

I tried the code below, but it's not working.

```
 $userID         = Auth::user()->id;

 $currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->where('employee_id', $userID)->whereIn('leave_status', [0, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

**Note:** If the last record is previous year, it should automatically make the button visible. But for the current year, it should apply any of the conditions for the rules.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// This gets last requests this year
$request = HrLeaveRequest::whereEmployeeId($userID)->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->whereIn('leave_status', [0,3,4])->latest()->first();

// OR you might remove the whereYear query to check with conditions
If(date('Y', strtotime($request->created_at)) < date('Y')) {

// This checks if the year is the previous year

}

$currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::where(['employee_id', '==' $userID], ['resumption_date', '>=', date('d-m-Y')])->whereIn('leave_status', [0, 3, 4])->latest()->first();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this:  If the last record is previous year, it should automatically make the button visible. But for the current year, it should apply any of the conditions for the rules.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing in the comment @Kescript